# Classical & weak solutions of Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

Consider the problem of an infinite square well
$$ V(x) = \begin{equation}
     \begin{cases}
       0, \qquad {\rm if}\quad0 \le x \le L \\
       \infty, \qquad{\rm otherwise}
     \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$
The time-independent Schrödinger equation is thus
$$
-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m} \frac{d^{2} \psi}{dx^{2}} = E \psi
$$
inside the well. We have a boundary condition $\psi(0) = 0 = \psi(L)$ and one can find that the solutions of this equation are
$$
\psi_{n}(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \sin(n \pi x/L).
$$

My question is:

1. Is this a classical solution? What is a good definition for classical solutions for differential equations?
2. Is it possible to get a weak solution for this equation (and boundary conditions)? What is a good definition for weak solutions?
3. Why are weak solutions important in the context of Quantum Mechanics? Is it possible to get a solution (with physical meaning) that, for example, has a non-continuous second derivative?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Your second equation can be written as $\ddot{\psi}+k^2\psi=0$ which has a simple, well known solution: $\psi=c_1\sin kx+c_2\cos kx$. Then apply BCs and normalise.

Comment: The factor $\sqrt{2/L}$ is found through normalisation, not from the BCs.

Comment: Sorry, i'm talking about weak solutions of differential equations in general (maybe in the distribution notion). I used infinite square well to exemplify and maybe I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Yes you're right. But my question is

1) Is this a classical solution? I though so because $psi_{n}$ has 2nd derivative continuous (not only the 2nd derivative...) and satisfies the boundary conditions.

The other ones I have no idea >_<

Comment: A better example for a well-known QM problem with a "weak solution" might be the "delta-function potential" problem.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert What do you understand by a 'weak solution'?

Comment: @Gert:  Roughly, a solution for which not all the derivatives appearing in the ODE exist at all points, but which still satisfies the ODE in a distributional sense.  For example, the solution to Schrodinger's equation delta-function potential does not have any well-defined derivatives at the location of the potential, but we can still write down a solution for which the integrals of the solution over some range are equal to the integrals of the Schrodinger equation over any range.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Oh I see now, long time ago. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. That solution is classical since the function is smooth.
2. All solutions of that equation are classical due to elliptic regularity of the (here $1D$) Laplace operator, since the equation does not contain non-smooth known functions.
   A weak solution is a locally $L^2$ function which satisfies the  (linear) differential equation and where the derivatives of the function are computed in terms of "weak derivatives", i.e., interpreting the function as a distribution. I stress that a distributional solution is an even weaker notion of solution. A weak solution is in fact  a function (up to zero measure set), a distribution is not necessarily a function instead.
3. Weak solution are of *fundamental relevance* in QM because the observables are selfadjoint operators that are *extensions* of the familiar differential operators and their domains are made of $L^2$ generally non-smooth functions. The stationary Schroedinger equation, if one insists on a differential equation, can only be intepreted in weak sense.
   However, elliptic regularity-like theorems  (in particular some therems due to Weyl) finally prove that the found solutions have some regularity. For instance if there is a potential $U$ with finite discontinuities, the weak solutions must be $C^1$ and $C^2$ outside the singularitues of $U$.